# What is the sha256sum check sum for Ubuntu studios 22.04?

Tags: checksums

I’m trying to make sure the iso image is good. I’m a noob so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SHA256SUM checksum for the ubuntustudio-22.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso file for installing Ubuntu Studio 22.04 is 3fe6fa9a17fa7a4b34b2ec7ff3b9500d354ca644aedcc37096b923f14247f504

The source of this link is [Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS Release Notes](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/).

Comment: Ty so so much. It matched appreciate it a million times over!!